# Train a Caffe CNN with Scale Parameter

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I've adapted the train_val.prototxt from the bvlc_reference_caffenet to implement a VGG-16 clone in Caffe and was able to train it with a GTX 1050 with `batch_size: 6` and `base_lr: 0.0648 (~ 0.01 * sqrt(256/6) ~ 0.01 * sqrt(42))`. However, I would like to scale the input data from [0;255] to [0;1] since the target platform for this CNN has a limited accuracy. To scale the data I introduced `scale: 0.00390625` parameter (this was taken from the Caffe LeNet example which runs fine on the target platform). But with the `scale` parameter the accuracy does not increase (> 40000 iterations) and the loss also does not change during training.

How can I train this CNN with the `scale` parameter?

train_val.prototxt

```
name: "ES VGG"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
    mirror: true
    crop_size: 224
    mean_file: "/local/datasets/imagenet/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/local/datasets/imagenet/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 6
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
    mirror: false
    crop_size: 224
    mean_file: "/local/datasets/imagenet/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/local/datasets/imagenet/ilsvrc12_val_lmdb"
    batch_size: 6
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1_1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "conv1_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv1_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "conv1_2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1_2"
  top: "conv1_2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1_2"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2_1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2_1"
  top: "conv2_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv2_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv2_1"
  top: "conv2_2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2_2"
  top: "conv2_2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2_2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3_1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3_1"
  top: "conv3_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv3_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3_1"
  top: "conv3_2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3_2"
  top: "conv3_2"
}
layer {
  name: "conv3_3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3_2"
  top: "conv3_3"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3_3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3_3"
  top: "conv3_3"
}
layer {
  name: "pool3"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv3_3"
  top: "pool3"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv4_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool3"
  top: "conv4_1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4_1"
  top: "conv4_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4_1"
  top: "conv4_2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4_2"
  top: "conv4_2"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4_3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4_2"
  top: "conv4_3"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4_3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4_3"
  top: "conv4_3"
}
layer {
  name: "pool4"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv4_3"
  top: "pool4"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv5_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool4"
  top: "conv5_1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5_1"
  top: "conv5_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv5_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv5_1"
  top: "conv5_2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5_2"
  top: "conv5_2"
}
layer {
  name: "conv5_3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv5_2"
  top: "conv5_3"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool5"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv5_3"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc6"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc6"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.01
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
}
layer {
  name: "drop6"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc7"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.01
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu7"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
}
layer {
  name: "drop7"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc8"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1000
    weight_filler {
    type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.01
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
layer {
  name: "accuracytop1"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracytop1"
  accuracy_param {
    top_k: 1
  }
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "accuracytop5"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracytop5"
  accuracy_param {
    top_k: 5
  }
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

solver.prototxt

```
net: "models/es_vgg/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 1000
test_interval: 1000
base_lr: 0.0648
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100000
display: 20
max_iter: 18900000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "models/es_vgg/es_vgg_train"
solver_mode: GPU
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide your input by `255` you need to multiply the weights of your first conv layer `"conv1_1"` by `255` to compensate for this change.
Look at [net surgery](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) to see how this can be done.

For example (in python):

```
import caffe
net = caffe.Net('models/es_vgg/train_val.prototxt', caffe.TEST)  # no .caffemodel weights supplied - weights are randomly init
# scale kernels of first conv layer by 255
net.params['conv1_1'][0].data[...] = 255. * net.params['conv1_1'][0].data
# save the scaled weights
net.save('models/es_vgg/init_scaled.caffemodel')
```

Now you need to start your training with `'models/es_vgg/init_scaled.caffemodel'`.

Comment: It seems to me that the net-surgery is done after I've trained a model?

Comment: @konze if you fine tune, then you can do the net surgery on the pre trained weights. if you train room scratch you just need to scale the weight_filler

Comment: I‘m still not sure what net-surgery does and how it helps me to use the CNN with [0;1] instead of [0;255]? Since I‘m using Xavier as filler I‘m not able to scale my weights. Should I use a different filler?

Comment: @konze you can either do net surgery after random init, or use gaussian filler with scaled std

Comment: Again, I don‘t get what net-surgery is for and how I should use it. The link you provided (https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) does not seem to address my problem. Could you give me a more extensive example in which my problem is addressed?